# Unit test on java code

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I have some problems with a few lines of code which remains to reach 100 percent.

```
if (object== null) {
            errors.reject("some error");
        }
```

Project uses Spring Framework and its class `org.springframework.validation.Errors` How can i make a unit test on this fragment.

The second fragment that i can not test is this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.getName().length(); i++) {
                int x = (int) model.getName().charAt(i);
                if (x < 33 || x > 126) {
                    errors.rejectValue("name", "some error");
                    break;
                }
            }
```

I hope that some one will help :)

**EDIT:**

```
public void validate() {
if (object== null) {
            errors.reject("some error");
        } 

        if (model.getName().equals("")) {
            errors.rejectValue("name", "some error");
        } else if (model.getName().length() < 6) {
            errors.rejectValue("name", "some error");
        } else if (model.getName().length() > 30) {
            errors.rejectValue("name", "some error");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < model.getName().length(); i++) {
                int x = (int) model.getName().charAt(i);
                if (x < 33 || x > 126) {
                    errors.rejectValue("name", "some error");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: We have no idea what you've *tried* to test either of these, or what the problem is... please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: @Jon Skeet i can not copy more code because this is not a study project.

Comment: We don't need to see your real code. We need to see a short but complete example demonstrating the problem you're facing. If you can't show us that, we can't help you.

Comment: @rockStar , obfuscate it ...

Comment: @Jon Skeet i will edit my question in a few minutes.

Comment: @Jon Skeet i hope now it is more clear.

Comment: Nope, as you *still* haven't shown what you've tried in order to test the code, nor what the result is in terms of which part isn't being tested.

Comment: The errors object should be injected by spring. your test can create its own errors object and set it on your validator. it's unclear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to get 100% coverage?

As @engineer mentioned [What is a reasonable code coverage % for unit tests (and why)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90002/what-is-a-reasonable-code-coverage-for-unit-tests-and-why)

It seems that the most likely culprit is insufficient `branch-coverage`. Meaning all the possible paths through your if condition `(x < 33 || x > 126)` are not evaluated. This is impossible as `x` will never be both greater than `126` and less than `33`.

There are `4` Possible Branches through an if condition like this.

> true || true << Both conditions will never evaluate to true at the same time.
>
> false|| true
>
> false||false
>
> true || false

It is only possible to cover `3` of `4` branches.

Comment: It's an *or* condition, not an *and* condition. It's certainly possible for `x` to be either less than 33 *or* more than 126.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt But not all 4 possibilities can be covered.

Comment: @rockStar , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90002/what-is-a-reasonable-code-coverage-for-unit-tests-and-why ...

Comment: @Manu *which* 4 possibilities? I only see two, `x < 33` and `x > 126` and it's certainly - easily - possible to cover these

Comment: @BlakeYarbrough There are only two *branches*, the branch where `x < 33 || x > 126` is `true` and the branch where it is `false`. The branches are created by the `if` statement, not by the components of the logical expression. You are listing the truth table of a boolean expression, but branches are something different. By your reasoning, almost no logical or expression would be possible to test because the left and right sides normally do *not* overlap