# How to made the code coverage to 100%

Tags: php, phpunit

Recently I started to write PHPUnit test. And this is my model code.(I used CodeIgniter 3).

**Account_model.php**

```
class Account_model extends CI_Model
{
    ...

    public function select_by_seq($seq = '', $select_columns = [])
    {
        try {
            $bind = [':a_seq' => $seq];

            // check $select_colums is exist in table
            if ($this->check_column($select_columns) === false)
            {
                throw new Exception('columns illegal', 201);
            }        

            ...

            $sql = "select ....
                    from {$this->db->dbprefix('account')}
                    where a_seq = :a_seq";

            $query = $this->db->query($sql, $bind);

            // ===== this always not runing. =====
            if ($query === false)
            {
                // ===== this always not runing. =====
                throw new Exception('sql errors', 301); 
            }
            else
            {
                return $query->result_array();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $error)
        {
            // set error log
            $this->set_error_log($error->getCode() . $error->getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This is my test **Account_model_test.php**

```
class Account_model_test extends TestCase
{
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        parent::setUpBeforeClass();

        $CI =& get_instance();

    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->resetInstance();

        loader('model', 'account_model');

        $this->obj = $this->CI->account_model;
    }

    public function test_select_by_seq()
    {
        $result = $this->obj->select_by_seq(
            $seq = '20160830'
        );

        $this->assertCount(1, $result);
    }

    public function test_select_by_seq_with_illegal_column()
    {
        $result = $this->obj->select_by_seq(
            $seq = '20160830',
            $select_columns = ['illegal']
        );

        $this->assertFalse($result);
    }

    ...
}
```

Because I write SQL by myself. I founded my PHPUnit test can't cover this `if ($query === false)`. And then my code coverage didn't achieve 100%. This problem  let me think the 100% is very important for the unit test? Or I had to modify my model code? Thanks your help.

Comment: If you aim for 100% coverage you missed the purpose of writing tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to always have code coverage 100%. But like you said there are situations when this is very hard to achieve. So having code coverage greater than 70% is quite good for most of the projects. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90002/what-is-a-reasonable-code-coverage-for-unit-tests-and-why) regarding the minimum code coverage required in project. But you should try to extract your business logic to its own class (Repository) and unit test it.

Answer (score 1):

> The `@codeCoverageIgnore`, `@codeCoverageIgnoreStart` and `@codeCoverageIgnoreEnd` annotations can be used to exclude lines of code from the coverage analysis. -- [PHPUnit Manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.codeCoverageIgnore)

There are examples in the PHPUnit [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.ignoring-code-blocks).

In a nutshell, wrap the code to be ignored by code coverage in `*Start` `*End` annotations:

```
if (false) {
    // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
    print '*';
    // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
}
```

Also see [What is a reasonable code coverage % for unit tests (and why)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90002/what-is-a-reasonable-code-coverage-for-unit-tests-and-why?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you show us your test file also, so we can be more clear about what you already have there.
Without knowing that, what I can suggest is to use Mock of query function, so it can return `false` as result. You can find more about Mocks [here](https://github.com/php-mock/php-mock)

Also as written before: you should not focus on 100% code coverage.

Comment: Hi, I had thought of that(use mock). But I just didn't use mock and achieve 100%. And I think your right. I should not focus on 100% code coverage.

Comment: I modify my article, I added my model test.